# Substring whole array content

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to come up with compact solution to process file which has positional numeric values for multiple categories, let say `[2..3]` is value for `A`, `[4..5]` for `B` and so on.

I need to sum all those values in one pass if possible, that what I like in Ruby. But I got a problem.

Processing array for ruby without loop with  `array.inject(0)`

```
contentX = ['a12334111','b3215555','c444389663']
content = [  12334111,  3215555 , 44489663]      # this OK

a =  content[1]
b = a.to_s[0..3]  # this string need to add
puts 'a:       ' + a.to_s + '  b:  ' + b.to_s

s = content.inject(:+)
s2 = contentX[0..3].inject(:+) #  Error here, no values calculated

puts 'Sum    ' + s.to_s
puts 'Sum2   ' + s2.to_s


#this is wanted output =================:::::
Sum2  = 888   # (123 + 321 + 444)
```

Comment: So you're trying to sum up `contentX`? You can't do this because they're not valid numbers, they're strings, and they start with letters.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Firstly, `[2..3]` is an array containing a single element the range `2..3`. I don't think that's what you mean, so you need to clarify that. You say `[2..3]` is "a value of A", but do not say what `A` is. Most importantly, whenever you give an example, you need so show what the desired return value is, which is of course a valid Ruby object. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Tx all, I need calculate only certain numeric portions of those strings, so I need to cut out a,b,c..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map the input to the three digits needed, convert them to integer and sum:

```
['a12334111','b3215555','c444389663'].
  map { |n| n[1...4].to_i }.sum
#⇒ 888
```

*Sidenote:* `Enumerable#sum` is the same as `inject(&:+)`.

Comment: Also learned the diff  between `[1...4]   ` vs `[1..4]`            2 or 3 dots in brackets